# Cubic Spline for a function

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

I have the function $f(x)=x^3$ and I need to find the cubic spline. The given points are: $\{-1, 0, 1\}$. What is the cubic spline for this function and what would a demonstration to this be?
I would say that the cubic spline is $g(x) = x$, but I don't know if it is true or how to prove it is right (demonstrate it).
So that is my question, which is the cubic spline for $f(x)$ and how can I prove that that is the cubic spline?

Comment: @ja72, maybe you could help?

Comment: Cubic spline interpolation is unique up to boundary conditions. So you should specify some.

Answer (score 1):

This function already is a cubic,
so the cubic spline 
which approximates it
is the function itself.

If this is not what you want,
please try to explain your question
more clearly.

Comment: I doubt about it since if you get the derivative in 1 or -1, it will be $f(x) = 3*x^2$ and this is 3, not 0!

Comment: Where have you said that you want the initial (or final) slope to be zero?

Comment: I took a course and from it I understood that it is know that $f'(x)' in the given points has to be 0.

Comment: Actually, for a "natural' cubic spline, you want $f''(x) = 0$ at the endpoints. Is that what you want?

Comment: You're better at explaining than some online courses :)). I was talking about some linear splines, but indeed. The thing I need is to prove this for the Natural Cubic Spline, and indeed, it's like you said. But if I have $x^3, f''(x)=6*x$. Would the spline be $x$ or $x^2$? And how can I prove that that's the spline?

Comment: When you say linear splines, do you mean a piecewise linear function?

Comment: Long story short, I needed the Natural Cubic Spline. The Piecewise linear Function would be a point b, but from my understanding, you can ask only one thing, and for now, I am interested in the Natural Cubic Spline, Then in the Piecewise Linear...

Comment: So this would be the natural cubic spline? If yes, why is it so?